Convergence of Infinite Series: unable to spot mistake
The series in question is:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }n^2\left(\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-1+\frac{1}{2n^2}\right)$$
and I need to see whether or not it converges.
What I tried was taking the absolute of the term, and finding its limit (to check whether it diverges by $n-$th term test).
I obtained:
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty }n^2\left|\cos \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-1+\frac{1}{2n^2}\right| &= \lim_{n\to \infty }n^2 \left|1-1+\frac{1}{2n^2}\right| \\
&= \lim_{n\to \infty }n^2 \left(\frac{1}{2n^2}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}.
\end{align}$$
The series is supposed to diverge as the limit of its partial sums is different from zero. I think the answer is supposed to be that the series converges according to graphing software, but I am unable to spot the error in my calculations.

A very common mistake. You can't compute the limit by parts, changing $\cos(\frac{1}{n})$ to $1$ while keeping the other terms with $n$. This is just false. The limit of the general term is equal to $0$, this can be easily checked using L'hopital's rule.

I see now, thanks! In that case, how would one go on about solving a series such as this when when trig functions are involved?

use the Taylor expansion of the cosine

@user133287 The terms after $\cos$ should remind you of the first few terms of the Taylor expansion of $\cos(x)$. Write down the expansion and see what you get if you substitute $x=\frac{1}{n}$.

You first just let one $n$ go to infinity, then the other? By this reasoning $$\lim_{n}n\cdot\frac1n=\lim_{n}n\cdot 0=0.$$

@Mark Viola showed the convergence. If you continue the expansion, you should get the "exact" value. of the summation.

In fact, you do not need to know anything at all about Taylor's Theorem or Taylor's Series.  Please see my posted solution for a way forward that relies on pre-calculus tools only

Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.

@user133287 And please feel free to up vote and accept an answer as you see fit. ;-)

I thought it might be instructive to post a solution that does not rely on use of Taylor's theorem, but instead uses trigonometric relations and inequalities only.  To that end, we now proceed.


Note that we have
$$1-\cos\left(\frac1n\right)=2\sin^2\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)\tag1$$
Furthermore, in THIS ANSWER, I showed using basic trigonometry only that the sin function satifies the inequalities for $x>0$
$$x-\frac{x^3}{6}<\sin(x)< x\tag2$$
Using $(1)$, we can write for $n\ge 1$
$$\begin{align}
n^2\left(\cos\left(\frac1n\right)-1+\frac1{2n^2}\right)&=-n^2\left(2\sin^2\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)-\frac1{2n^2}\right)\\\\
\end{align}$$
Then, using $(2)$, we find that for $n\ge 1$
$$0<-n^2\left(2\sin^2\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)-\frac1{2n^2}\right)<\frac1{24n^2}-\frac1{48n^4}$$
Inasmuch as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2}$ converges, the series of interest does likewise.  And we are done!

Without showing Taylor expansion of cosine, the answer must look like a mystery to OP.

Hi Mark ! Long time no see you ! Cheers

@ClaudeLeibovici Hi Claude, my friend!  I hope that you are doing well.

@dnqxt One does not need a Taylor expansion.  Please see the revised posted solution

Did you intentionally mix the two common notations $\sum_{n\ge 1}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$ ?

@jjagmath Yes I did.  I've edited accordingly.  Thank you for the heads up.  Much apreciated.  And (+1) for your comment

RHS of $(2)$ should be $\sin x$.

@dnqxt Actually, Equation $(2)$ was missing an inequality sign.  I've edited accordingly.  Thank you for the note

@user133287 Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

@user133287 And please feel free to up vote and accept an answer as you see fit.  ;-)

As suggested by comments above, we start with Taylor expansion of cosine (around zero):
$$\cos x = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - \frac{x^6}{6!} + ...$$
Thus,
$$\cos x -1 < - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} $$
Substituting this in the summation term:
$$n^2\left(\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-1+\frac{1}{2n^2}\right)
< n^2\left(-\frac{1}{2n^2}+\frac{1}{4!n^4}+\frac{1}{2n^2}\right) = \frac{1}{4!n^2}
$$
It is known that $\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}.$ Therefore our sum is also convergent.

And we don't even did to rely on Taylor's Theorem. See my posted solution.  ;-)
